# Find entity id in database

Tags: 7, database, entities

I am currently moving a website from Drupal. The information I need to transfer is divided to many DB tables and connected through entity_id (That is my understanding, I have no experience in Drupal).

E.g. I have 2 MySQL tables:
`users` — contains `uid`s, passwords and emails
`field_revision_field_user_profile_phone` — contains phone numbers and `entity_id`s

I believe there should be a table that matches `uid`s and `entity_id`s, that will let me build a MySQL query to join them, but I can't find it.

How do I join those tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the database that contains `entity_id` (`field_revision_field_user_profile_phone` in this case) there is a column named `entity_type`. That would be a name of the table which contains both `uid` and `entity_id`.

Answer (score 2):

**For the second question how to join tables:**

You can use Drupal `db_select` or `db_query` in querying the database and joining tables.

This will list all users name, mail, and password.

Example:

**Using db_select**

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
$query->join('field_revision_field_user_profile_phone', 'ei', 'ei.entity_id = u.uid');
$query->fields('ei', array('field_user_profile_phone_value'));
$query->fields('u', array('name', 'mail', 'pass'));

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $result) {
  // ...
}
```

**Using db_query**

```
SELECT ei.field_user_profile_phone_value AS field_account_employee_id_value,
       u.name AS name,
       u.mail AS mail,
       u.pass AS pass
FROM users u
INNER JOIN field_revision_field_user_profile_phone ei ON ei.entity_id = u.uid
```

**Additional Resources:**

[Documentation of `db_select` function.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x)

[Documentation of `db_query` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x)